# What is the purpose of WebLogic JarBuilder Tool?

Tags: weblogic

I came across WebLogic JarBuilder Tool and [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/client/jarbuilder.html) has information on how to use it. But I am not able to find anywhere on what is the purpose of this tool and when we have to use this. Can someone please help me in understanding the use of this tool and if possible can it be explained with some examples.

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/client/basics.html#wp1069994:

> Prior to WebLogic Server 10.0, the weblogic.jar file was required for
>   T3 and WLS-IIOP client applications to provide WebLogic
>   Server-specific value-added features. For WebLogic Server 10.x and
>   later releases, client applications requiring these features should
>   use the wlfullclient.jar file instead of the weblogic.jar. See Client
>   Types and Features for more information on client types, features, and
>   class requirements.
>
> You can generate the wlfullclient.jar file for client applications
>   using the JarBuilder tool. See Using the WebLogic JarBuilder Tool.